# Multiple DTMFs defined to leave_conference

Tags: asterisk

I need to be able to define multiple DTMF digits to exit a CONFBRIDGE conference.  Once out of the conference, I need to know what DTMF digit was pressed.

I want to implement the following:
Press 4 for the previous conference
Press 6 for the next conference
Press the star key to exit the conference

Therefore, I need to define 3 keys for exiting the conference, but I need to know which key was pressed when I'm out of the conference.

I tried using dialplan_exec, but once you are out of the conference executing your dialplan snippet of code, you can't kick yourself out of the conference.  I tried using AMI commands and CLI commands and the command appears to work, but confbridge list confirms that you are still in the conference.  Therefore, if I have the code put me into another conference room, then confbridge list shows me as being in two conference rooms at the same time.

Any ideas???  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
exten => _X.,1,ConfBridge(500)
exten => _X.,2,Dumpchan
```

you will see variable it set on exit.

Comment: That is helpful but it does not show the DTMF digit that was pressed.